# Let A,B be sets and F(A), F(B) their respective free groups. Assume F(A) ≅ F(B). If A is finite, prove that so is B, and A ≅ B.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I thought I had this but apparently my idea wasn't even close. I'm not sure what I'm missing or need to consider. Thanks for any help!

Comment: I believe the standard way to do this, is (1) consider the abelianisation (2) tensor with a field (3) use linear algebra. But depending on your prerequisites, this may not be a helpful insight.

Comment: What was you idea? Sometimes it is a good idea to salvage (if possible). It does not matter so much it is inefficient, one can still learn quite a bit by trying.

Answer (score 2):

Let $C_2$ be the cyclic group of order 2. By definition of a free group, each map $A \to C$ uniquely determines a homomorphism $F(A) \to C_2$, so there are excatly  $2^{|A|}$ such homomorphisms. Hence if $F(A) \cong F(B)$ then $2^{|A|} = 2^{|B|}$.

This is enough to solve your problem. But if $A$ and $B$ are infinite, then I believe that the statement $2^{|A|} = 2^{|B|}$ implies $|A|=|B|$ is independent of ZFC. (But there are other ways of proving the result when $A,B$ are both infinite.)

Comment: I liked this stunningly simple proof which doesn't use abelianizations. +1

Comment: This feels like cheating!

Comment: This is just using the universal property of free groups. So is abelianizing. And in any case, any map from a free group to $C_2$ factors through its abelianization.

Comment: (And when $A, B$ are both infinite the set of homomorphisms to $C_2$ naturally acquires the structure of an $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector space of dimensions $|A|, |B|$ respectively.)

Answer (score 1):

If we were talking about free *abelian* groups, can you see why it's true? Can you see how this helps?

Comment: @Myself Yes unfortunately I haven't had much experience with what you mentioned except for introductory linear algebra.

excitingcorpse No I'm not really sure how that would make it true.

Comment: ah, so basically what happens is you go from $F(A) \cong F(B)$ to $fab(A) \cong fab(B)$, the free abelian group on $A$ and $B$. it's basically the same thing, except the universal property is stated for *abelian* groups instead of arbitrary ones. so you end up with $\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus A} \cong \mathbb{Z}^{\oplus B}$. then when you tensor with $\mathbb{R}$, you get $\mathbb{R}^A \cong \mathbb{R}^B$, and from linear algebra you can deduce the result you want. i'd just take it as given for now if you don't follow the details of this argument

Comment: What does tensor mean? I'm sorry but I'm unfamiliar with this concept.

Comment: @Searchdeeper to take the tensor product with. basically $\mathbb{Z}^n \otimes \mathbb{R} = \mathbb{R}^n$. so if you do it with both of (the abelianisations of) your free groups, you get $\mathbb{R}^n = \mathbb{R}^m$, and from linear algebra we know this is true only when $n = m$.